# Wrapping class in Proxy object TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a function that accepts an API interface (I've created a sample here), and wraps a `Proxy` around it, so that any calls to the that API's methods get intercepted, and I can do some logging, custom error handling etc. I am having a terrible time with the types. This is similar to another question I have asked ([Writing wrapper to third party class methods in TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040277/writing-wrapper-to-third-party-class-methods-in-ts/75041030#75041030)), but uses a completely different approach than that one, based on some feedback I got.

Currently I am getting
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | symbol' can't be used to index type 'API'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'API'.` which makes sense given that `sayHello` is not strictly a `string` as far as typescript is concerned, but I do not know the best way to be able to get methods on this class without uses the property accessor notation.

```
class API {
 sayHello(name: string) {
     console.log(“hello “ + name)
     return name

  }
}

export default <T extends API>(
  api: T,
) =>
  new Proxy(api, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof target[prop] !== "function") { // type error here with "prop"
        return target[prop]; // and here
      }
      return async (...args: Parameters<typeof target[prop]>) => {

        try {
          const res = await target[prop](...args); // and here
          // do stuff
          return res
        } catch (e) {
          // do other stuff
        }
      };
    },
  });
```

Is this possible in TS?

Comment: Proxies can't really be implemented with compiler-verified type safety; you'll probably have a better time just using type assertions and writing the types manually.  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKePW)?  Kind of confused by your example code since `res.data` will be undefined for `sayHello()`, but I tried to write the types to take into account how it works.  If that fully addresses your question let me know and I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That’s brilliant. The “data” field was a typo on my part. Thank you for the code example!

Comment: "*so that any calls to the that API's methods get intercepted*" - why use a `Proxy` for that? All you need to do is to decorate all the methods of the object.

Comment: @nickhealy if you have a typo you can [edit] it.  Do you want me to write up my code as an answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz edited my question. I think your code snippet answered my question so I’d be happy to mark it as an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently model the situation when a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) differs in type from its target object.  There's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#20846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20846), and I don't know if or when the situation will change.

For now if you want to do this you'll need to manually describe the expected return type of your proxy function, and use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) liberally inside the implementation in order to suppress any errors.  This means you'll need to verify that your function is type safe yourself; the compiler won't be able to help much.

Here's one possible approach:

```
const prox = <T extends API>(api: T) => new Proxy(api, {
  get(target: any, prop: string) {
    if (typeof target[prop] !== "function") {
      return target[prop];
    }
    return async (...args: any) => {
      try {
        const res = await target[prop](...args);
        return res;
      } catch (e) { }
    };
  },
}) as any as { [K in keyof T]: AsyncifyFunction<T[K]> };

type AsyncifyFunction<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ?
  (...args: A) => Promise<Awaited<R>> : T;
```

The idea is that `prox(api)` returns a version of `api` where every non-function property is the same, but every function property has been changed to an async version that returns a `Promise`.  So if `api` is of type `T`, then `prox(api)` is of [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{ [K in keyof T]: AsyncifyFunction<T[K]> }`, where `AsyncifyFunction<T>` is a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) utility type that represents the transformation of each property type.  If `X` is a function type with argument tuple `A` and return type `R`, then `AsyncifyFunction<X>` is `(...args: A) => Promise<Awaited<R>>`, using [the `Awaited<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) to deal with any nested promises (we don't want a `Promise<Promise<number>>` to come out of this, for example).

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
class Foo extends API {
  str = "abc";
  double(x: number) { return x * 2 };
  promise() { return Promise.resolve(10) };
}
const y = prox(new Foo());
/* const y: {
    str: string;
    double: (x: number) => Promise<number>;
    promise: () => Promise<number>;
    sayHello: (name: string) => Promise<void>;
} */
```

So, according to the compiler, `y` has a `string`-valued `str` property, and the rest of its properties are asynchronous methods that return promises.  Notice that the `promise()` method returns `Promise<number>` and not `Promise<Promise<number>>`.

Let's make sure it works as expected:

```
console.log(y.str.toUpperCase()) // "ABC"
y.sayHello("abc") // "helloabc"
y.double(123).then(s => console.log(s.toFixed(2))) // "246.00"
y.promise().then(s => console.log(s.toFixed(2))) // "10.00"
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAKBJaBvAsAKGtCYCeAEgKYggD2AFAHZgC2RAXDgC4BOAllQOYCUqm2bMDJUIZEEQB05LhQBEACxLk50ANTQa9HgOgBfTAYyZho5tAAOrMgA9oAXmgAeACrQiN5kSoATGAkQAPgowC3YmFz57QM0iAHdoeGsbPBCwgBp+LGguImYKZjBWXOYmMCo8TKsyCyYINk5eLMFodgAzaAK8CyIyDsLivIBtaosAXWgAQntHOTaAVypgZnYROT50bJbWPPnWKmgBkpHrcYBuXWwjbd396Eg8Jc7JF6KuCDKKqJjNluw2PDNP5CET1aA7GCOMBxMDscxHYajMYUF6SN4QHgXLZ-HbMPYHCFY4F6aDAMDMYAKTpEDb6S76In6dKGPiQe4Ve4wFDQIYAaVaBwA1kQ8H1oC4xkxYBBHsB2ngAGKLZarKiuPljGJ6LGYZjdIhwGVLeVKpYrESuGKONweLy+GAo17FD4CtpEVhwb6u93QABK0AA-LpHWjnVKvUkyLR2BAiE5YDC4UQfE5fYEYhEdRhQJAYAqyGR3J5vH44EggfUPbMwAAjYByRk+MjzGsSCg2JhUea0Gvu2m4-HQOwAKmgACYGbpqtHYxR+7cDpGZ1IIeIAG5ECgARgADHxtYYTKDzIDHNUbNR4tB85QeJjMAB6UemMF4Ji-QSVuoNbiM7BNlsJCYdtO27XtWAjaxlycLse3dQI-0sKCY0YTpIKjFCYLA+DENwQhlDIYCtFQytGnQ6C1zIdgfAQwxoGHB8j1EcQpBkCg8EkStJGYMgAFULB6VgAGFIE3O9oAfB9oDkWAACEhLkTAOLw4hSEoORa3rPhJOkpQ1M0xSMA4gDW03LcxwAZh4bilCoChIRiF8WOkMhZAgbiyAVdgbGTCgxzvbSpLkMcABYADZJB3HdDI46cULnGzvHshxHNBZy2PcnivJ8nw-ICiSgt3SLoswIA)

Answer (score 0):

You can try add [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures) to your class:

```js
class API {

 /* -- index signature -- */
 [index:string|symbol]: any;

 sayHello(name: string) {
    console.log("hello" + name)
  }
}

export default <T extends API>(
  api: T,
) =>
  new Proxy(api, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof target[prop] !== "function") {
        return target[prop];
      }

      /* -- had to store it in a variable -- */
      const data = target[prop];

      return async (...args: Parameters<typeof data>) => {

        try {
          const res = await target[prop](...args);
          // do stuff
          return res.data;
        } catch (e) {
          // do other stuff
        }
      };
    },
  });
```